# Interprocess communication via a database

Tags: java, database, design-patterns, ipc

If I have 2 processes running in different nodes and they share a database, is there a pattern that one node be able to send some notification to the other process via the database?
Is some kind of polling a table normally used or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a database, you can insert entries into a table on the producing side and poll to find new entries on the consuming side.  This may be the simplest option for your project.

There are many possible alternatives such as JMI, RMI, Sockets, NoSql databases, files, but without more information it's not possible to tell if these would be better. (Often simplest is best)

Comment: So use polling?There is no other kind of mechanism?And I have to use DB as it already is there

Comment: If you are going to use a database for messaging, you have to use polling.  Databases are not designed for messaging so don't expected it to be pretty, but it will work if your requirements are not too large.  BTW Just because you are using a DB doesn't mean you can't use a proper messaging system like JMS for messaging (I am not saying to have to but you shouldn't dismiss the idea because you have a DB)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of polling (which translates into burning not only CPU cycles but in this case also database resources and bandwidth), how about this? if you were using Oracle you could define a trigger ON UPDATE for the table you want to be notified and call a Java Stored Procedure (JSP) from the trigger. The JSP could then use whatever notification mechanism to notify the other component about the change. This is not going to be extremely fast but well ...

The proper way would be to have the component updating the Database sending a parallel notification to the other component and again use any available technology for this RMI, JMS etc

Answer (score 1):

Polling is not an optimal solution.  If you have a large number of clients or users, the database is going to be kept busy answering to the pollsters.

Users blocking or waiting for an update is much preferable, if possible.  Users generally prefer a responsive system.

The two main criteria to consider before deciding are the maximum number of concurrent users and how quickly users needs to be notified of the event they have expressed an interest in.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution than polling, if your database supports it, is select() or something like inotify().  For instance, PostgreSQL supports select(), so you can do a non-busy-loop while waiting for input into the DB. That being said, [Database-as-IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database-as-IPC) is considered an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is just polling on another process.

However, if you want another process receives the data change immediate, you then should consider using some notification mechanism, such as rpc, http request, etc.